# Volatile Table in Stored Procedure - Teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I create a stored procedure as follows:

```
replace PROCEDURE mydb.sp_Insert_Values ( 
   IN  lastExecDate timestamp 
) 
SQL SECURITY CREATOR 
BEGIN 

CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE vt_ref_table_1
(
    Ref_Id integer,
    Ref_Unit_Type varchar(50)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

insert into mydb.vt_ref_table_1
select Ref_Id, Ref_Unit_Type
from mydb.ref_table_1;  

INSERT INTO mydb.Time_Series_Table
select
  t1.TD_TIMECODE
, t1.Time_Series_Meas
, t1.Time_Series_Curve_Type_CD 
, t1.Ref_Unit_Type
, t1.Ref_Id 
, t1.created_on
from
        (
            select 
            meas_ts as TD_TIMECODE 
            , ref_table_1.Ref_Id as  Ref_Id
            , meas as Time_Series_Meas,
            , Time_Series_Curve_Type_CD
            , Ref_Unit_Type
            , current_timestamp as created_on
            from mydb_stg.Time_Series_Table_Stg as stg
            left join mydb.ref_table_1 as ref_table_1
            on ref_table_1.Ref_Id = stg.Ref_Id
            where stg.created_on >= :lastExecDate
        ) as t1
        left join mydb.Time_Series_Table as t2
        on t1.TD_TIMECODE=t2.TD_TIMECODE
        and t1.Time_Series_Curve_Type_CD = t2.Time_Series_Curve_Type_CD
        and t1.Ref_Id=t2.Ref_Id
        where t2.Ref_Id is null
;   
END;
```

It compiles but when I call it this error is thrown:

> Only a COMMIT WORK or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.

I know the error is related to the volatile table but I don't know how to correct it.

Why I need the volatile table:

The reference table has a row-level-security constraint. If I use it directly I get another error:

> A multi-table operation is executed and the tables do not have the
>   same security constraints.

Teradata Version: 16.20

Mode: ANSI

Comment: If you run in ANSI mode you must add `COMMIT;` after the Create Table, as the error message clearly states :-) And check if that automatically created `PRIMARY INDEX(Ref_Id)` is a good one, otherwise change it.

Comment: Hi, this was exactly the problem. I inserted a `COMMIT WORK;` just after the create statement and now it work, novice error :-)

Answer (score 0):

workaround:

1. create VOLATILE table first in your session
2. create procedure in the same session

Answer (score 0):

you need a 'COMMIT WORK'statement after you create statement i.e
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE vt_ref_table_1
(
Ref_Id integer,
Ref_Unit_Type varchar(50)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
COMMIT WORK;